# Can any creature be tamed?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, monsters, skills

In my game, my PCs are always trying to tame a creature or monster with their Nature skill. Can any and all creatures/monsters be tamed and controlled/kept by using Nature or any other skill?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Answer (score 8):

NO.

The verbiage for [Nature](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/skill.aspx?id=16) reads:

> Make a Nature check to teach a natural beast a simple trick (come, fetch, heel, stay, and so forth). This use of the skill is usually part of a skill challenge, which might take much longer than an encounter to complete. (RC 148)

Natural Beast is a specific monster type and *only* monsters with both the Natural and Beast subtypes can be trained. Do a compendium search for the full list as there are over 650 of them. A few examples from the list are cat, dog, White Wyrmling Dragon and a Giant Snail.

That said, if your players do find a natural beast to train, they must first calm it, and then training it is certainly an option, it might be difficult though.

Comment: Not to mention that only describes training a tamed beast, *not* taming a wild one.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'd expect taming a wild one to be an *extended* (several week at least) challenge

Comment: I wonder if you can tame/train non Natural Beasts by the use of a separate skill?

Comment: @MC_Hambone not per the descriptions of those skills